# Office.js use data URI with addFileAttachmentAsync?

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to use a data URI to add a text file attachment to an email using Office.js, version 1.3. I seem to be getting a failure with error code 9007. Does anyone know if the API supports using a data URI? I don't see examples anywhere so perhaps it does not.

Example data URI - 'data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D'

Comment: This scenario is currently not supported, that is correct. Where do you get the data URI - is it hardcorded into the JS file of the add-in?

Comment: It's generated on the fly depending on what options users have selected within the add-in. I suppose I could write an HTTP service that would take an options list and send back a .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, this API does not support data URIs. New ideas and feature requests can be added to outlook add-in developer User Voice page here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-add-in-outlook